# Best way to do a recursive function within a for loop iterating over an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, setinterval

I have an array of letters:

```
const letters = ['a','b','c','d'];
```

I also have a function which takes a string argument **letter** and returns a concatenation of that letter and a random number.

```
function letterNumber(letter) {
   console.log(letter + '-' + Math.random());
}
```

What I am looking to do is to iterate over the **letters array** and for each item in the array to run the **letterNumber function** N times every X milliseconds, with the array item being passed to the **letter function argument**.

What would be the best (and most performant) way to achieve this? Thanks a lot!

**EDIT**

I have now made it work by moving the **let iterator=0;** within the nameless function in the code below. Is there a better way of doing this if faced with a lot of values in the **letters** array?

```
const letters = ['a','b','c','d'];
const interval = 1000;
const runCount = 5;

function letterNumber(letter) {
    console.log(letter+'_'+Math.random());
}

for (let i = 0;i<letters.length;i++) {   
    (function(i) {
        let iterator=0;
        let iter = setInterval(function() {
                if (iterator > runCount-1) {
                    clearInterval(iter);
                } else {
                    letterNumber(letters[i]);
                    iterator++;
                }
        }, interval)
    })(i);
}
```

Comment: have you tried something which comes close to the wanted task? please add a wanted result.

Comment: @NinaScholz I have edited the post, I have now found a solution but I still have a question around performance? Is this the most performant way of achieving this task if we have an array with loads more values?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT - I apologize, I initially misunderstood your question. Here's how I would recommend running through this.

---

It's been a while since I've worked with Javascript, so bear with me. Instead of the `setInterval()` and `clearInterval()` combination, I would go with the `setTimeout()` function. I don't know the technical ins and outs of it, but much like the `setInterval()` function you provide the `setTimeout()` function two arguments - the function/command you wish to run, then how long you wish to wait. This is how I would utilize this:

```
let iterator = 1;

function letterNumber(letter) {
    console.log(`${letter}_${Math.ceil(Math.random() * 25) }`);
}

while (iterator <= runCount){
    setTimeout(() => letters.forEach(letterNumber), interval * iterator);
    iterator++;
}
```

You'll notice in the second argument passed into the `setTimeout()` function, I provided the value of the interval times the iterator. The reason is that `setTimeout()` is executed as synchronous code, and the multiple calls to `setTimeout()` all run at the same time. Each call to `setTimeout()` creates asynchronous code that will execute later, after the given delay. Which is why the amount of the delay has to be produced dynamically. Otherwise, if I were to use this code:

```
while (iterator <= runCount){
    setTimeout(() => letters.forEach(letterNumber), interval);
    iterator++;
}
```

It would queue each call to the `setTimeout()` function, then each call will wait the specified amount (in this case, each call would be waiting for 1 second) then all run at the same time.

So when we run it with a dynamically created interval (`interval * iterator`), each call waits 1 second longer than the previous call to run, resulting in a delay between each return.

I hope I explained that well enough, sorry if I may have missed out on some of the details, but this should provide you the results your looking for.

Another thing to take note of, in the code I provided, I set the iterator to 1, and the condition for the while statement is testing for the iterator begin less than or equal to the runCount. I started with 1, so that the first result of the `setTimeout()` function was delayed by one second.

If you wish to have the first result set returned immediately, you can change the initialization of the iterator variable to 0, and change the while condition to a plain less than statement like so:

```
let iterator = 0;

...

while (iterator < runCount){
   ...
}
```

Another thing to look out for is what `Math.random()` does. Currently, it provides you with a decimal value between 0 (inclusive) and 1 (exclusive). In other words, possible values range from 0 to 0.99999 repeating. So if you want to get an integer value, you can do something like this:

```
function letterNumber(letter {
   console.log(letter + '-' + (Math.ceil(Math.random() * 25) )
}
```

The above code would provide you integer values from 1 to 25.

If you want more details, you can take a look at [this MDN article on the Math.random() function.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)

I really hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but as far as I can tell this just iterates through the letters array and runs the function once per array item. What I need is this function to run multiple times every x amount of time for each array item until it is told to stop

Comment: You're correct, I did misunderstand the question. I have edited my answer to hopefully provide you for more of what you're looking for. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could get rid of the closure and use a local scope for item/letter, `iterator` count and `iter`.

```js
function letterNumber(letter) {
    console.log(letter + '_' + Math.random());
}

const
    letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
    interval = 1000,
    runCount = 5;

for (const item of letters) {
    let iterator = 0,
        iter = setInterval(function() {
            if (++iterator > runCount) clearInterval(iter);
            else letterNumber(item);
        }, interval);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```